# Is there any easy way to let spreasheet viewers filter content separated by Comma?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I have a video game list which contains their Genres in a second column, I've add each genre separated by Comma, all in one cell for each game, and I need a convenient way for viewers to filter (search) Multiple genre values.

Is there any way to make it easy or is there any add-on, script or macro to add such feature?

Image of a part of file:
[image]

.

.

***link to file:***
[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kVNV7AaEE_fFjmhVfCkSUqIldB_wkAw7tKQcX3gBouY/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewers cannot modify anything in a spreadsheet they have read-only access to, so the only way they can filter data is to use a [temporary filter view](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681).

Try conditions like these:

- **Text contains >** `3D`
- **Custom formula is >** `=regexmatch(B2:B, "(?i)3D|strategy")`

There are also paid add-ons such as [Awesome Table](https://awesome-table.com/).